# Не работают кнопки на сайте из-за плагина, в чем кроется причина?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Простой способ найти решение, это отключать каждый плагин. Был найден плагин который мешает работе других плагинов.

Но в чем проблема?

Не работают кнопки чата, или кнопки лайков. Плагин использует скрипты. Что чат плагин, что тот, который мешает.

Как устранить такой конфликт плагинов WordPress?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут дело не в конфликте, а в синтаксической ошибке. Эта ошибка в 445 строке.
Для более детальной информации нужна ссылка на ресурс.

Comment: там значится код, который я никак не могу найти кстати в файлах плагина https://yadi.sk/i/Ou-u_dth3Qv6iM

Comment: ссылка не работает

Comment: быть не может. но я заменила сайт на код который там был на этой строке

Comment: там конкретно  if (messages.length > 0 &amp;&amp; 'ascending' == 'ascending') { не нравится почему то возникает конфликт двух плагинов если тут не в версиях скриптов дело. тогда в чем. почему именно один плагин мешает всем другим? хотя браузер указывает ошибку на сам плагин чата почему то

Comment: `if (messages.length > 0 &amp;&amp; 'ascending' == 'ascending') {` замените на `if (messages.length > 0) {`

Comment: спасибо. помогло. странно было что отключая другой плагин. чат не имел проблем. хотя оказалось что ошибка в строчке темы плагина чата

Comment: @bilberry, общайтесь, если проблема решена, пометьте этот ответ как верный